# strpos() madness- why doesn't it work?

Tags: php, strpos

See the following issue:

```
$str = "video-23984"; // returns false
$str = " video-23984"; // returns true
$search= "video";

if(strpos($str,$search)) {
  echo "True";
}else {
  echo "False";
}
```

Why in the world does `$str = "video-23984"` return false? And what can I do to make it return true?

Comment: `is_int(strpos(…))` if you're looking for the boolean test, otherwise it returns bools **or** integers (where `0` is the likely outcome).

Comment: what the hell mario, this isn't a duplicate. The other question is different, even tho it's related to the same function and it's return.

Comment: Big warning from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) - `Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.`

Answer (score 0):

In the first string the word `video` is in the first position, which means `0`.

In the second it's in the second position, which means `1`.
Since you're returning it into an if, the 0 is a boolean for `false`. That's why you're getting `false` as a result.

Comment: For a complete answer, you should discuss the differences between `==` and `===` (and `!=` and `!==`)